# Plotting Uncertainty for a Sample of Functions

Tags: plotting, visualization

I am trying to produce a plot showing the variation in a sample of functions. It should look like [this plot](http://andrewgelman.com/2012/08/26/graphs-showing-regression-uncertainty-the-code/) or [that plot](http://blog.enthought.com/general/visualizing-uncertainty/). 
I tried to use `SmoothDensityHistogram`. Even for the following simple example this does not look right. Do you have other suggestions?

My approach so far was:

```
dx = 0.01;
functionSample = 
Table[noise = Random[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5]]; 
Table[ {x, x (1 - x) + noise}, {x, 0, 1, dx}], {i, 1, 60}];
var = Flatten[diff, 1];
ListPlot[functionSample[[All, All]], Joined -> True]
SmoothDensityHistogram[var, 
ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Black}, #] &)]
```

Producing

[image: ListPlot][image: SmoothDensityHistogram]

Maybe things can be improved by choosing a small bandwidth of the kernel in x direction and a larger in y direction of the underlying kernel smoother.

Answer (score 4):

Just for visualisation purposes you can use `Filling`:

```
dx = 0.01;
n = 10;
functionSample = Table[noise = Random[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5]];
                       Table[{x, x (1 - x) + noise}, {x, 0, 1, dx}]
                      , {i, 1, n}];


ListPlot[Evaluate[{Mean[{##}], ##} & @@ functionSample], 
         Joined -> True, Filling -> (# -> {1} & /@ Range[2, n + 1]), 
         PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness@.02, Orange], Sequence @@ Array[Thin &, n]}, 
         FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity@.3, Gray]]
```

[image]

```
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness@.02, Orange], Sequence @@ Array[None &, n]}, 
FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity@.1, Gray]
```

[image: enter code here]